# Not able to access ContentDocumentLink on Site VF page's Controller(without sharing)

Tags: apex, soql, force.com-sites, contentdocumentlink, access

**SOQL:**

```
[SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = {{reocrdID}}]
```

OR

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM {{sObjectAPIName}} Where id = {{recordID}}
```

On Anonymous window: returns list of files attached with particular record

On Internal VF page controller (without sharing): returns list of files attached with particular record

**On Site VF page controller (without sharing): returns empty list**

**Is there any configuration/access permission needs to be granted for site guest user?**

Answer (score 0):

I think that queries directly on Content are picky and don't always display everything other users own, even if it's visible to the user by permissions or by way of `without sharing`.

Perhaps you can try querying the record instead, and subquerying its `ContentDocumentLinks` list?

Comment: Thanks Charles! But only available link between ContentDocument and LinkedEntity is ContentDocumentLink record. As per my understanding, there is no other option.

Comment: Yes but what I'm saying is, query it parent-to-child instead. For example if it's an Account, `SELECT Id, (SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM Account WHERE Id = :acctId`.

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks for inputs! Tried it, still empty result. Same results as mentioned in question.